# Google Drive API (java): Add a datatable/chart to a spread sheet (SpreadsheetEntry)

Tags: java, google-drive-api, google-visualization

I have a SpreadsheetEntry (a spread sheet) that I have created:

```
SpreadsheetEntry sheet = ...;
```

What I want to do is graph some data and then print that graph to the spread sheet.  To do this I have defined a DataTable from the Google Visualization API:

```
DataTable table = DataTable.create();
```

Now I want to embed the table into the sheet.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

There's a sample implementation here [Embedding a Chart in a Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets#embedding-achart-in-a-spreadsheet) but it's in JS. Since you're using Java, try using the [Data Source Java Library](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/dev/dsl_about) which is suggested by the docs.